# Avoid re-fetching data while streaming in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I've just started playing with streaming data in Expressjs.

Not entirely sure, but I think the request will start to execute the handler again. For example, here is my handler:

```js
import getDataAsync from "./somewhere";

function handler(req, res) {

    console.log('requesting', req.path);

    getDataAsync()
        .then(data => {
            let stream = renderContent(data);
            stream.pipe(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.end();
        })
}
```

What I found was, it continue to print out `console.log('requesting', req.path)` (which I think will re-execute `getDataAsync`).

My question is:

Is it true it will re-execute `getDataAsync`?
If it does, what's your approach?

Thank heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Node JS is non-blocking, so if you were to make a request to an endpoint with this handler again then it will execute. The handler will call getDataAsync() and then the handler gets removed from call stack. The process is repeated for each request.

If you want the handler to wait out the stream before it calls it again you could do:

```
import getDataAsync from "./somewhere";

let streamComplete = true;

function handler(req, res) {
    
    if(!streamComplete) {
      res.end();
    }
  
    console.log('requesting', req.path);

    getDataAsync()
        .then(data => {
            streamComplete = false;
            let stream = renderContent(data);
            stream.pipe(res);
            stream.on('end', () => streamComplete = true);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.end();
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did need to sort this problem out in one of my projects. Node or in fact any other environment/language will have the same issue, that once you start streaming the data to one client, it's rather hard to stream it to another. This is due to the fact that once you do this:

```
inputStream.pipe(outputStream);
```

...the input data will be pushed out to output and will be removed from memory. So if you just pipe the inputStream again, you'll have some initial part of the data missing.

The solution I came up with was to write a `Transform` stream that kept the data in memory and you can reuse it afterwards. Such a stream will have all the original chunks and at the same time when it catches up with the first request, it will just keep pushing the chunks directly. I packaged the solution as a npm module and published so now you can use it.

This is how you use it:

```js
const {ReReadable} = require("rereadable-stream");
// We'll use this for caching - you can use a Map if you have more streams
let cachedStream;

// This function will get the stream and 
const getCachedStream = () => 
    (cachedStream || (cachedStream = 
        getDataAsync()
        .then(
            data => renderContent(data).pipe(new ReReadable())
        ))
    )
    .then(readable => readable.rewind())
```

Such a function will call you `getDataAsync` once and then will push the data to a the rewindable stream, but every time the function is executed the stream will be `rewound` to the begining.

You can [read a bit more about the rereadable-stream module here](https://github.com/signicode/rereadable-stream).

A word of warning though - remember, that you will keep all that data in memory now, so be careful to clean it up if there's more chunks there and control your memory usage.